# Apache2 internal server error not being logged

Tags: apache-2.2, php, php.ini, 500-error, logging

I'm doing some web development with the Laravel framework, and I have my jQuery set up so that it sends a request on click of a button to a PHP file, which then returns the result back to my jQuery.

However, every time I click this button I get an Internal Server Error.   **This is not the problem; rather the error is that my Apache error log does not make any mention of this 500 Internal Server Error.** In fact, it doesn't really log anything except for `[notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down` and `[notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) PHP/5.4.4-14+deb7u12 configured -- resuming normal operations`.  All that being said, my access.log shows the Internal Server Error happening:

`"POST /testing/public/apps/devicecheckout-checkoutdevices HTTP/1.1" 500 833 "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/testing/public/apps/devicecheckout-checkoutdevices" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36"`

In my php.ini file, I have `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT` and `log_errors = On`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does that `SIGTERM` error message happen every time you make the request or does it happen at seemingly random times unrelated to the requests to the PHP file?  Also, are you using any PHP extensions in this PHP script?

Comment: It happens only when the Server goes down for maintenance, or when I do a `sudo service apache2 restart`.  As for your other question, I am using the Laravel framework, which is a large PHP based framework.

Comment: Laravel is not a PHP extension.  You can find the list of PHP extensions you have installed by running `php -m` on the command line or checking the output of a `phpinfo()` page. For example, if you are talking to a Rabbit server in your PHP script then you are likely using the [AMQP PHP](http://pecl.php.net/package/amqp) extension.

Comment: Actually, a more important question: Do you get other PHP errors in your Apache error log?  They might be logged somewhere else if you have set the `error_log` variable in your `php.ini`.

Comment: Ahh I see, sorry about that.  Here are my PHP extensions:

[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
intl
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib

Comment: Also, I just checked my phpinfo and here is the value for `error_log`: `error_log => no value => no value`..which is strange because I thought I fixed that in my `php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

You may have PHP syntax errors.

Try to use `php -l script-name.php` to see if everything is right with your file.

Comment: No syntax errors were detected in my file according to that command.